# I am trying to export functions from context into another file to use with jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to run some functions in my test file with jest. I am new at this so please be kind. I am importing this function from a context file in my application.

```js
let isProduction2 = () => {
    if (production) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

export {
    ProductProvider,
    ProductConsumer,
    ProductContext,
    isProduction2
};

import {
    isProduction2
} from './context'

test('Fake Test', () => {
    expect(isProduction2).toBeTruthy();
});
//Error   Jest encountered an unexpected token
```

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not executing your function (i.e `isProduction2`) in your expect statement. You are currently just passing a reference.

Instead of

```js
test('Fake Test', () => {
    expect(isProduction2).toBeTruthy();
});
```

it should be

```js
test('Fake Test', () => {
    expect(isProduction2()).toBeTruthy();
    //note the `()` after function name. This executes it and returns the result.
});
```

Comment: This is helpful but i am still getting the error i cant even console.log the function

Comment: The same as before i cant seem to import context functions from my context file for some reason